# Show the list of all users who edited a node in Drupal 7

Tags: views

Usually, I display the name of the user edited a node at last, not the ones in the middle. I want to display a list of all the users who edited a node. Is that possible by using Views or any other way? They do so [here](http://drupal.org/documentation).

Comment: Do you mean revisions tabs in Drupal Documentation page?

Comment: i found the answer here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51063/including-multiple-authors-in-authoring-information-for-a-drupal-7-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you thought that part would be closed source ? No!
Check http://drupalcode.org/project/drupalorg.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/drupalorg_handbook/drupalorg_handbook.module which adds this functionality to book nodes. This module was built for drupal.org but it's not that difficult to get it modified for your needs!

If you want to do this in Views,

1. Create a view with `Content Revisions` in under "Show". uncheck page display,check 'make a block', and click continue and edit. You will be taken to Views UI. Now, remove existing fields and add a new relationship to `Content: Author`.
2. Add new field to user name from the just-added relationship.
3. Add new contextual filter to the node ID. Set the default action to take argument from URL. Then, expand click on Query settings and enable Distinct.
4. Give the block a title and admin name.
5. Place block where you want.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ayesh, but the relation should be to "Content revision: User". And it displays the same username multiple times for multiple revisions. But I want to show an username only once, no matter what the number of revisions is. Any help?

Comment: sorry... updated answer. see #3